# Split two columns simultaneously and make data in long format with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data

```
d.df <- read.table(header=T, text="V1 | V2 | V3
A + C | Cat + Dog | Type 1
B + D | Bird | Type 1
A + D | Cat + Fish | Type 2" ,stringsAsFactors=F, sep="|", strip.white = TRUE)
require(data.table)
setDT(d.df)
```

I want to make this data in long format spliting the two variables simultaneously, so the desired output is like this

```
A Cat Type 1
C Dog Type 1
B Bird Type 1
D Bird Type 1
A Cat Type 2
D Fish Type 2
```

This way I could split based in one variable

```
output <- d.df[, list(V2 = unlist(str_split(V2, " \\+ "))), by = V1]
```

but if I try both together I get an error `recycled with remainder.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(d.df, c("V1", "V2"), sep = "+", direction = "long")

#   V1   V2     V3
#1:  A  Cat Type 1
#2:  C  Dog Type 1
#3:  B Bird Type 1
#4:  D Fish Type 1
#5:  A  Cat Type 2
#6:  D Fish Type 2
```

---

`separate_rows` from `tidyr` also works in this case

```
tidyr::separate_rows(d.df, V1, V2, sep = "\\s+\\+\\s+")
```

Comment: Nice, is there any way around the case I edited now in the data?

Comment: @Roland `separate_rows` gives the expected output with `cSplit` you can do `dt <- cSplit(d.df, c("V1", "V2"), sep = "+", direction = "long");
dt[, V2 := zoo::na.locf(V2)]`

Comment: Or probably this is better : `dt[, c('V1', 'V2') := lapply(.SD, zoo::na.locf), .SDcols = c('V1', 'V2')]`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to fall back on the base R recycling:

```
setDT(d.df)
ans <- d.df[, as.data.frame(lapply(.SD, function(x) trimws(strsplit(x, "\\+")[[1L]]))), 
    .(rn=d.df[,seq(.N)]), .SDcols=V1:V2][, 
        TYPE := d.df$V3[rn]]
ans
```

output:

```
   rn V1   V2   TYPE
1:  1  A  Cat Type 1
2:  1  C  Dog Type 1
3:  2  B Bird Type 1
4:  2  D Bird Type 1
5:  3  A  Cat Type 2
6:  3  D Fish Type 2
```